# Не могу понять принцип работы алгоритма в C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм

```
 namespace EBPOEM
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = 0;
            String Poem = "";

            while (x < 4)
            {
                Poem = Poem + "a";
                if (x < 1)
                {
                    Poem = Poem + " ";
                }
                Poem = Poem + "n";

                if (x < 1)
                {
                    Poem = Poem + " oyster";
                    x = x + 2;
                }
                if (x == 1)
                {
                    Poem = Poem + "noys";
                }
                if (x < 1)
                {
                    Poem = Poem = "oise";
                }
                x = x + 1;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(Poem);
        }
    }
}
```

По учебнику, в ответе вылезает окошко с надписью "a noise annoys an oyster". У меня же "an oysteran".

Перепроверил множество раз, не могу понять где я совершил ошибку. Да и в учебнике не объяснили, как мы получили такую "поэму" по заданным условиям.
 Объясните пожалуйста, программированием занялся совсем недавно. Смекалки не хватает...

Comment: А не проще в отладчике пробежать и все самому увидеть?

Comment: Хорошо, буду учиться работать с откладчиком.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал вам пробежать код в отладчике, и все самому увидеть.

Работа с отладчиком:

- Поставить *breakpoint* (точку останова) - <kbd>F9</kbd> на нужной строке. При достижении этой строки, исполнение программы приостановится, и вы сможете в студии посмотреть значения всех переменных.
  Предлагаю поставить на верхнюю строку метода `button1_Click`
- <kbd>F10</kbd> / <kbd>F11</kbd> - выполнить один шаг и снова остановиться.
  <kbd>F10</kbd> - без захода внутрь метода.
  <kbd>F11</kbd> - с заходом внутрь при условии, что есть куда заходить.

---

Еще хочу указать на ошибку в этой строке:

```
Poem = Poem = "oise";
```

Полагаю, должно быть:

```
Poem = Poem + "oise";
```

---

Вот рабочий вариант:

```
int x = 0;
String Poem = "";

while (x < 4)
{
    Poem = Poem + " a"; // Добавлен пробел перед a
    if (x < 1)
    {
        Poem = Poem + " ";
    }
    Poem = Poem + "n";

    if (x > 1)  // изменен знак условия с < на >
    {
        Poem = Poem + " oyster";
        x = x + 2;
    }
    if (x == 1)
    {
        Poem = Poem + "noys";
    }
    if (x < 1)
    {
        Poem = Poem + "oise";  // исправлена ошибка, указанная выше
    }
    x = x + 1;
}
Console.WriteLine(Poem);
```

Comment: Спасибо! :) Как мне отметить ваш ответ лучшим?

Comment: @Klugge [Что делать когда кто-то ответил на мой вопрос?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Благодарю, добрый человек :)

Answer (score 1):

На глаз, сдается мне, что в условии:

```
if (x < 1)
{
    Poem = Poem + " oyster";
    x = x + 2;
}
```

сравнение должно быть в другую сторону (x > 1). Может, и ошибаюсь, времени нет проверить.